# Scala build tool error in Ubuntu

Tags: ipython

I installed Apache spark(1.5.2) and IPython(0.12.1) notebook in my Ubuntu 12.04. Before creating a profile for IPython specifically for PySpark, I want to install scala build tool. I followed the following query to build sbt.

```
wget http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb `

#Install the repository
sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb

#Refresh
sudo apt-get update
```

I got the below error while running apt-get update.

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/spark$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I searched the web to solve this issue. As per the instructions in the net the issue is in the line 2, I commented the line 2 ie

```
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

Below is the actual output of **/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ precise main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

After commenting, still I am getting Malformed line 2 in source list **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list** error.

How can I solve this issue? As I need to solve this issue and need to create profile in IPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about the malformed line 2 in file **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list**, instead of the /etc/apt/source.list file.

You can try to do the same thing to comment out the second line (or fix it with the correct format) of the **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list** file.